# Fiber bundle with locally constant transition maps

Tags: general-topology

We call a fiber bundle with locally constant transition maps if $\varphi_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\to U_i\cap U_j$ is constant map for any $U_i$ and $U_j$. At first I thought such fiber bundle can only be trivial bundle, but I quickly found that the Mobius band, as an $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$, gives a counter example. But I still guess that such a fiber bundle is trivial up to a finite cover. Is it correct?

Comment: You've not explained what the $U_i$ and $\varphi_{ij}$ are supposed to be. If it's supposed to be an open cover and corresponding transitions maps (which I'd assume), then the domain and codomain are off.

Comment: I think it would also help if you clarified what your definition of fiber bundle is (I can think of several possible ones). One of them implies that any such fiber bundle is *always* trivial up to a finite cover (if you’re speaking of open covers and not covering maps, that is).